# What does half sum mean?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Just a short question: I'm reading about Newton polynomials (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206077) and I'm wondering, what the "half-sum of the positive roots" (page 9 'notation') is. Is it something like
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{\alpha\in R^{+}}\alpha ?$$
I can't find a definition of this term anywhere.

Comment: Yes.$\phantom{}$

Comment: @anomaly how did you comment with so few characters. is that a high rep privilege?